# FileNotFoundException using XSLT with Spring 3

Tags: xslt, spring-3

I got following exception using XSLT with Spring 3:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Can't load XSLT stylesheet from `/WEB-INF/xsl/home.xsl`; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [`/WEB-INF/xsl/home.xsl`]

Comment: Looks like you don't have file in given location.